# PHP search and return exact matches only from a csv file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The below code searches my csv file but returns multiple results when I only want it to return exact. For example; in my csv file I have the following on separate lines: Henry Jones, Sarah Jones.
If I search for Sarah Jones it is returning both based upon the matching surname. 
Can anyone help? I have tried multiple things but with no joy! Thank you very much in advance!

```
<?php
if ( !isset( $_GET['q'] ) && !isset( $_GET['update'] ) ) {
    echo '<div class="alert">' . $txt_hint . '</div>';
}
// Only on FORM Submit
if ( isset( $_GET['q'] ) && !empty( $_GET['q'] ) ) {
    // Remove the Regex Char
    $words = str_replace( '#', '', $_GET['q'] );
    // Open CSV.File
    $file  = fopen( $CSV_Filename, 'r' );
    // Supports any Number of Search-Words
    $words = explode ( ' ', $words );    
    // Make the Search-Words safe to use in Regex (escapes special characters)
    $words = array_map( 'preg_quote', $words );
    // Make Regex e.g. '/Project|Name/i' means 'Project or Name' case (i)nsensitive
    $regex = '#' . implode( '|', $words ) . '#i';







    // Set Skip-First-Line Helper
    $flag = true;
    // Loop each Line
    while ( ( $line = fgetcsv( $file ) ) !== FALSE ) {
        // Skip first Line (only Healine, no real Data)
        if ( $flag ) {
            $flag = false;
            continue;
        }
        // Split Line
        list( $Details_1,$Time_Started,$Details_3,$Job_Name,$Time_Complete ) = $line;
        // Check if Search-Match AND $Time_Complete is empty
        if ( preg_match( $regex, $Job_Name ) && $Time_Complete == '' ) {
            // Show Data in Browser
            echo '
              <div class="box">' . $Time_Started . '</div>
              <div class="box">' . $Details_3 . '</div>
              <div class="box">' . $Job_Name . '</div>

              <div class="box noBorder"><a class="update" 
               href="' . htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?update=' .
               htmlentities( urlencode( $Job_Name ) ) . '">' . 
               $txt_completebutton . '</a></div><br>
            ';
            // Set Search-Hit Helper
            $hit = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are specifically creating a regular expression that lists all the individual terms as _alternatives_, with `|`. If you don’t want that … well then why are you doing it?

Comment: If you want to find only _exact_ matches(?) - with search term `Sarah Jones`, find _only_ records that have _exactly_ `Sarah Jones` in the target column, nothing more and nothing less - then why regular expressions in the first place?

Comment: As CBroe mentioned you don't need a regular expression, try strpos() instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I removed the '|' which prevented both names being returned but would not return the name 'Sarah Jones' either? I am no php expert so any guidance very much appreciated!

Comment: Sorted! I was so close, can't believe how little I had to do to get this sorted!! Thanks again. Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that with a fullMatch regex and a fullMatch flag.

If a full match is found, the flag fullMatch is triggered and then only full match can be found in the search

```
// Make Regex e.g. '/Project|Name/i' means 'Project or Name' case (i)nsensitive
$regex = '#' . implode( '|', $words ) . '#i';
$regexFullMatch = '#' . implode( '', $words ) . '#i';
$isFullMatched = true;
.
.
.
if ( preg_match( $regex, $Job_Name ) && $Time_Complete == '' ) {
      if(preg_match( $regexFullMatch, $Job_Name )){
        // Show Data in Browser
        echo '
          <div class="box">' . $Time_Started . '</div>
          <div class="box">' . $Details_3 . '</div>
          <div class="box">' . $Job_Name . '</div>

          <div class="box noBorder"><a class="update" 
           href="' . htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?update=' .
           htmlentities( urlencode( $Job_Name ) ) . '">' . 
           $txt_completebutton . '</a></div><br>
        ';
        // Set Search-Hit Helper
        $hit = true;
        $isFullMatched = true;
    }
    else if(!$isFullMatched){
        // Show Data in Browser
        echo '
          <div class="box">' . $Time_Started . '</div>
          <div class="box">' . $Details_3 . '</div>
          <div class="box">' . $Job_Name . '</div>

          <div class="box noBorder"><a class="update" 
           href="' . htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?update=' .
           htmlentities( urlencode( $Job_Name ) ) . '">' . 
           $txt_completebutton . '</a></div><br>
        ';
        // Set Search-Hit Helper
        $hit = true;
    }
}
```

Note : this code is not optimized, but it give you an idea !

Comment: Hi Lucas, that is really helpful thank you very much!! I have added the regexFullMatch which has stopped the full name from returning a hit but sadly at the moment it does not return a hit on the full name. It looks as though the space between the names is possibly causing an issue? Thanks again for getting me to the next step!!!

Comment: I'm glad this answer help you, don't forget to accept the answer if the problem is solved !